# How to create a database with robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, database

I want to create a new database by using robomongo. Click "create database" then I write database name.  when I click to create nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First check your mongo server will start or not , if not then start as `mongod` from command line and then create a database.

Comment: What version of Robomongo, MongoDB, and O/S are you using? Also, what is the database name you are trying to use? When you click the Create button the dialog should close and the tree view in Robomongo should refresh showing the newly created database.

Comment: mongo server is working. Robomongo 8.3 mongodb and windows server 2012. I did what you said but nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

i've encountered this problem today with the same version of RoboMongo. The problem was that RoboMongo currently doesn't support MongoDB storages version 3.x. 
More about this topic is available on the 
[Robomongo blog](http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-future/)

New version of robomongo will be available on 17. January and mongo versions 3.x will be supported.

Answer (score 1):

i suppose you have mongo installed and checked.

- open up terminal/command prompt and run mongod. if there is a problem you may need to repair it

  ```
  $mongod --repair
  ```
- in terminal you should have your mongo server waiting for connection
- now run robomongo, and click on 'Connect' icon (File > Connect)
- in connection settings window set the name, and other settings as you want.
- click 'Save' and then connect using the connection you set up.
- right click on your connection and select 'Create Database'.
- type the name and you have your database.
- to add table (i.e. collection), expand your database and right click on 'Collections' > 'Create Collection...'.
  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue in Robomongo 0.8.5 on Windows. Tried to create the collection from the shell instead and it revealed that my account was not authorized to do that. Robomongo failed silently in such a case.

Comment: this does not appear to be an answer. Is it?

Comment: It is the answer. Robomongo should show some kind of message telling why creating a collection failed, but it doesn't. Trying to achieve the same from the shell should reveal what the real problem is. In my case it was the lack of write permission.

Answer (score 1):

First is reason:
robomongo 0.8.5 can't read store engine 'wiredTiger':
cmd show:
"Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'. And mogodb storage engine wirte in 'wiredTiger'

Second: Solution:

> 1) delete every thing in database:
>
> goto   "C:\data\db" then delete all !!!!
>
> 2) open cmd, point the path to some where you can write command and
>   type this:
>
> mongod --storageEngine mmapv1

Answer (score 0):

If using Robo 3T (new name for Robomongo) and you create a DB in Robo 3T but don't see it listed in the shell via `show dbs`.

You need to also create a collection in the new DB in Robo 3T and after that, it will show with `show dbs`.